# STM32 USB HID Keyboard skipping key presses

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device, stm32cubemx, keyboard

I have an STM32F3DISCOVERY evaluation board which has an stm32f3 mcu on it. I am trying to use the board to emulate a USB keyboard.

I used the STM32CubeIDE to enable USB communication, configure the clock to use the external 8MHz crystal, and set up the USB HID device middleware. I also made the necessary edits to the automatically generated `usbd_hid.c` and `usbd_hid.h` files to configure the USB device as a keyboard.

My first goal was to type a repeated string of characters. My intended output of characters is "aabacadaeafagahaiajakala", (a-l with "a" printed after each letter). Here is the relevant portion of my `main()` function:

```
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  extern USBD_HandleTypeDef hUsbDeviceFS;
  uint8_t HID_buffer[8] = {0};

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while(1){
      for (uint8_t w=0x04; w<0x10; w++){
          HID_buffer[2] = w;
          USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, HID_buffer, 8);
          HAL_Delay(30);
          HID_buffer[2] = 0x04;
          USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, HID_buffer, 8);
          HAL_Delay(30);
      }

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

I can compile the code and upload it to the board. I plug the board into a USB port on my computer and it is recognized as a keyboard, but the sequence of letters it types is wrong. I just get "bcdefghijkl" and then repeats. It skips the first "a" and doesn't print an "a" after any of the letters as expected.

I've tried changing the delay times but I always get the same result. Am I doing something wrong in software, or is it maybe a hardware issue somewhere?

*UPDATE*

I tried a somewhat less convoluted test that hopefully gets more to the root of the problem. This time I just wanted to press the letter "a" every two seconds. I press the key for 100ms then release it for 2000ms.

When I upload this code and plug in the board, the letter "a" is printed repeatedly, as if the key is just being held down and never released. It seems to be completely ignoring my 2 second release of the key. Any thoughts on this result? Again, here is the relevant code:

````
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  extern USBD_HandleTypeDef hUsbDeviceFS;
  uint8_t HID_buffer[8] = {0};
  int control_bit = 0;

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while(1){

          if(control_bit == 0){
              HID_buffer[2] = 0x00;
              USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, HID_buffer, 8);
              HAL_Delay(100);
              control_bit = 1;
          }else{
              HID_buffer[2] = 0x04;
              USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, HID_buffer, 8);
              HAL_Delay(2000);
              control_bit = 0;
          }

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```
````

Comment: What's delay times have you tried?

Comment: `It skips the first "a" and doesn't print an "a" after any of the letters` isn't it easier to say `it doesn't print "a"`

Comment: @jsotola Yes... but I thought that the omission of the first "a" was significant and wanted to highlight that. But on top of that, I'm not sure why I posted this question with such a strange test case to begin with. I've updated the question adding a hopefully more simple test.

Answer (score 2):

`USBD_HID_SendReport()` does not send the HID report immediately. Instead, the transmission is controlled by the host. So `USBD_HID_SendReport()` more or less prepares an HID report to be picked up by the host. If the last report hasn't been picked up, the new one is discarded. `USBD_HID_SendReport()` returns `USBD_OK` anyway.

So before sending a report, you need to check whether the endpoint is idle. I'm not sure how it's done properly. Try it with:

```
uint8_t HID_IsIdle (USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev) {
    return ((USBD_HID_HandleTypeDef *)pdev->pClassData)->state == HID_IDLE;
}
```

Also note that if you want to achieve two consecutive key presses of the same key, you need to send an additional HID report without the key pressed in-between. Otherwise the host thinks that the key is still being pressed and does not count it as a second press.

BTW: The interval for picking up the HID report is controlled by the USB descriptor, in particular the `bInterval` field of the endpoint descriptor. The effective pickup interval is slightly different. It's usually rounded up to the next power of 2.

Comment: I now call the proposed HID_IsIdle function repeatedly in a while loop until the bus is found to be idle between my calls to USBD_HID_SendReport. I still get the same result.